# What are some algorithm to search for a combination based on a set of minimum requirements?

Tags: algorithm, search

Let's say I want to choose itemA and itemB from listA and listB respectively to make a combination. Each item carries 1~3 attributes, let's say attribute x, y and z. Also, there's an attribute that acts as a filler, say f, which can be replaced with x, y or z if needed. Now I want to search with a set of minimum requirements.

For example,

```
list A:
itemA 1: x, 2z
itemA 2: y, z, f

listB:
itemB 1: y
itemB 2: x, f

minimum requirement:
2x, y, 2z
```

The result should return itemA 2 and itemB 2, sinze it'd be `x, y, z, 2f`, which I can replace an f with x and another with z. It should also return (in the same call or another call, I can change that myself) itemA 1 and itemB 2, which gives `2x, 2z, f`, which I can replace the f with a y. Combinations that have 5x, 5y, 5z is also a valid answer because it satisfies the minimum requirement.

Except I need to choose 6 items from 6 lists, with 5 of the lists having over 100 items, and the number of attribute is about 100. Furthermore, there are different "grades" of attributes, and each grade has its own filler; filler of a said grade can only be replaced by attribute within the same or lower grade(s).

Is there an algorithm I can look into and modify? I just need a pointer to get started, as all I've been able to come up with have largely been brute force. I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: One thing to clarify is whether the solution must match the desired conditions exactly. For example assume the desired conditions are 2x, y, 2z. Is a solution with 3x, y, 2z a correct solution?

Comment: @user3386109 good point, yes that solution does work, the condition is more like a minimum requirement, I'll edit the question now, thanks!

Comment: I think the general class of algorithms to look at is [integer linear programming](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/linear-programming/info) (ILP). But I don't have enough experience to know how well ILP will handle the fillers. It can definitely solve the problem without fillers. But with fillers, I don't know.

Comment: @user3386109 okay, I'll do some research on that, really appreciate it!